# Detect installed applications (software dev) on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, applications

I'm a first time Mac user.

Aside from checking out the installed applications on my Applications folder, are there other ways to find out what applications have been installed on my OS X Lion?

When I tried out the Terminal, and then assumed that the IRB (Interactive Ruby) or Ruby was installed, so I typed "irb" and it did work.  It ran the Interactive Ruby and I was typing simple Ruby commands then!

I tried typing "python" too and the Python prompt then appeared.  I typed some basic Python commands like "print 'hello world'" and it worked too!

I was thinking if there was a way to find out just like the Add/Remove Programs that I was used to when I was still using Windows XP/7 back then.

Cheers!

Comment: I wanted to find out what programs or tools that were installed in my OS X Lion, especially ones that are related to web development?  I was asking myself this questions: "This this already have Apache installed or not?", "Is MySQL already installed here", "What about Ruby?".  I was assuming these questions because of my experience on some Linux installations were these tools are bundled with the installation of the OS.

Comment: I don't miss "Add Remove Programs" at all, but sometimes I miss having the kind of overview you are after. There's nothing wrong with listing the contents of `/bin` and `/usr/bin` just to get a quick peek at what in on your path. Sqlite is there.

Comment: Apache is there.  You can enable it in `System Preferences-> Sharing -> Web Sharing`.

Comment: You may also find that some of the programs Apple packages with the OS are a bit outdated.  I'm going to start the *MacPorts vs. HomeBrew* shout-outs with **MacPorts** as my pref.  These two can provide you with access to more and more current packages.

Comment: Is there a way we can determine the versions of this installed programs?

Comment: Many unix programs tak --version as an argument - also not all Linuxes bundle MySql and ruby

Comment: @Panoy, if you are worried about versions already you may want to look into MacPorts, Fink, or HomeBrew.  MacPorts has many recent packages available.

Answer (score 2):

Apple Menu > About This Mac >

In the resulting window: (More Info)

In the side bar of the resulting window: Software > Applications

Columns presented:

Application Name | Version | Last Modified

Click on a row to see more details:

- Kind (architecture)
- 64 Bit
- App Store
- Get Info String
- Location (in the file system)

I see Python this way (3 different versions actually) but not PHP or Ruby.

Comment: I think I have ruby installed as I'm playing with the Interactive Ruby on the Terminal but it didn't show up with I've done the procedure you're talking about.  Hmmm, I might check up again just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for executable files with `mdfind 'kMDItemContentType==public.unix-executable'`. It seems to exclude files inside application bundles and files with a filename extension though.

`mdfind 'kMDItemContentType==com.apple.application-bundle'` would search for application bundles.